# IE 8 Behaves Strangely with Javascript/Jquery with version differentiation from 8.7600 and 8.7601

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

IE 8 Behaves differently with Javascript/jQuery with compared to Other browsers but it also behaves strangely with IE 8 different versions 8.7600 and 8.7601.

I have a javascript and jQuery which works fine in 8.7601 and not in 8.7600.??????? Any Ideas why it is doing that???

jQuery is like following

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var objLocation = $('#location');
    $('#' + objLocation.val()).addClass('hover');
});
```

Please help me with solutions..!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: which part is not working?

Comment: More likely to be one of them being in Compat mode and one in Standard mode than any difference between the two revisions of IE8.

Comment: And I had tried with `$(document).ready(function(){})` but did not worked at all in IE 8 so I used `$(window).load()`. It is basically for highlight the parent page name in menu when URL is matched.

Comment: @Spokey it is not about specific part... It is like the output differs in both versions.

Comment: @Spudley Both are running in Standard mode

Comment: The thing is, as far as I'm aware the difference between those two revisions of IE8 is nothing more than a couple of small security patches. There's nothing in your code that would have any bearing at all on that. Maybe you should try breaking it down a bit more and work out which line exactly is giving you the trouble.